# Strange problem with Wampserver 2.0 - rollback change of file

Tags: php, windows, wamp, wampserver

I have running Wampserver 2.0 on Windows 7, I get some php files, insert them on www folder... and when I tried edit any with running server, its rollback for few seconds (in notepad++ I get alert with massage: "some other program modified that file, do you want to reload it?") when I reload file I got old version of file.

With server turned off, I can edit files, but when it goes on again files rollback again. Please help.

Comment: notepad++ or eclipse, in both there is same issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cause may not related to Wampserver. It does not replace changed php files even if the server get requests for the particular file in the time of editing (before saving changes). This may be due to an automated script running in your computer such as a deplyment script. Please check whether if there any such script / service running.