# Windows7 - strange problem with dir/files attributes

Tags: php, windows-7

In addition to my previous question: [Strange problem with Wampserver 2.0 - rollback change of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850550/strange-problem-with-wampserver-2-0-rollback-change-of-file)

I suppose on my administrator account I can't change access attributes on some files. I change it (probably successful) but after reopen properties it comes back.

Could It be the reason of strange files behaviour? (after I edited some, save, and get that the file was changed by another program - in notepad++ and eclipse).

EDIT: File has also UNIX filesystem and I am working on windows7, could it be the reason?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Are the files local on your computer, or are they on a network share?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by an anti-virus software scanning your files after saving them.

Comment: Thanks for try but turning off antyvirus doesn't help.